# AssetManager unable to resolve dependencies of tmx file LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Please explain to me where I am going wrong. Here is my code. I have been trying to load a level I designed in tile in LibGDX, but have been hit with

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: level_1_better.tmx
```

Here is my TileTest.java file

`package com.mygdx.game.mytile;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapProperties;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class TileTest extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private TiledMap map;
    private TiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private AssetManager manager;
    private Integer tileWidth;
    private Integer tileHeight;
    private Integer mapWidthInTiles;
    private Integer mapHeightInTiles;
    private int mapWidthInPixels;
    private int mapHeightInPixels;
    
    @Override
    public void create () {
        manager = new AssetManager();
        manager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader());
        manager.load("level_1_better.tmx", TiledMap.class);
        manager.finishLoading();

        map = manager.get("level_1_better.tmx", TiledMap.class);
        
        MapProperties properties = map.getProperties();
        tileWidth         = properties.get("tilewidth", Integer.class);
        tileHeight        = properties.get("tileheight", Integer.class);
        mapWidthInTiles   = properties.get("width", Integer.class);
        mapHeightInTiles  = properties.get("height", Integer.class);
        mapWidthInPixels  = mapWidthInTiles  * tileWidth;
        mapHeightInPixels = mapHeightInTiles * tileHeight;
    
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(320.f, 180.f);
        camera.position.x = mapWidthInPixels * .5f;
        camera.position.y = mapHeightInPixels * .35f;
        
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.5f, .7f, .9f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();      
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        manager.dispose(); 
    }
}`

My file level_1_better.tmx is in the assets folder's root directory. And hyptosis_tile-art-batch-1.png is the sprite sheet it is referencing to create the tile level.

Answer (score 1):

It's because something referenced by your `level_1_better.tmx` file cannot be found.

That can, for example, be the tile-set and/or the images that make up the tile-set.
If you open the **.tmx**-file you'll see that it references other files, you might see a line similar to this:

```
<tileset firstgid="1" source="terrain.tsx"/>
```

If the `terrain.tsx` file cannot be found by the `AssetManager` you get the error message you're seeing.
If you open the **.tsx** file it might have references to image files, for example like this:

```
<image source="terrain.png" width="396" height="198"/>
```

That image file must also be available to the `AssetManager`.

When using **Tiled** to create **.tmx** files resources will be referenced with relative paths, you need to make sure they're structured and placed correctly in the `assets` folder.

Comment: Thanks man, turns out I didnt have the level_1_better.tsx in the same folder as the tmx file. After I added it there, it all worked out